# Can you do geometry with persistent homology?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, reference-request, topological-data-analysis

## Setup

In practice, persistent homology of data $X$ is often used to infer the homology of the underlying (Riemannian) manifold $M$ that the data is sampled from.

However most filtrations (Vietoris, Čech, ...) depend on the metric on $M$ and the resulting Persistent Modules also depend on that metric, and not just on the homology of $M$.

## Questions

Thus I wonder, what properties of the Riemannian metric on $M$ can be reconstructed from persistent homology? Can we use persistent homology to construct some invariant of the metric?

Do you know of any research in that direction?

There is the paper [Persistent homology detects curvature](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13196) which seems to be a step in that direction.

## 'Persistent homology of $M$'

Of course persistent homology starts with data $X$ sampled from $M$ and it is not immediate how to get an object only depending on $M$ and not on a specific sampled dataset. For that, one could use the average of a vectorization of the persistence modules. For instance the average persistence landscape would only depend on $M$ and might hold some information of the metric.

Here is the same [question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453018/can-you-do-geometry-with-persistent-homology)